# How to make dropdown option link to page on button click

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that currently goes to a link as soon as an option is selected. I want to add an add to cart button instead so that they select a drop down option, THEN click add to cart.

```
<div class="custDrop1"><select onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"> 
<option>Green</option> 
<option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4988">Blue</option> 
<option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4989">Clear</option>
<option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4990">Purple</option>
<option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4991">Black</option>
<option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4992">Ivory</option>
<option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4993">Smoke</option>
</select>
</div>
    <div class="product_reg"><span id="newprice">$146.00</span> (Reg. $218)</div>

    <div class="product_addtocart">
<a href="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4988" class="todayshowaddtocart">
ADD TO CART
</a>
```

So that link at the bottom, should be a button or input instead, and the select on change up top should be different js, but I cant seem to get it right. Ideas?

Just to be clear, when the option is selected, they should have to click the bottom link/button to submit that url change.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `onchange` handler and assign an `ID` to your `select`, then using javascript you can get the selected value from a function triggered by a button/link click.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to just update the cart button link on option value change, then i have made small changes in your program, i have assigned id to your cart button and create a new javascript function:

```
<div class="custDrop1">
<select onchange="updatelink[this.options[this.selectedIndex].value]"> 
    <option value="">Green</option> 
    <option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4988">Blue</option> 
    <option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4989">Clear</option>
    <option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4990">Purple</option>
    <option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4991">Black</option>
    <option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4992">Ivory</option>
    <option value="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4993">Smoke</option>
</select>
</div>
    <div class="product_reg"><span id="newprice">$146.00</span> (Reg. $218)</div>
    <div class="product_addtocart">
<a id="cartbutton" href="/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4988" class="todayshowaddtocart">
ADD TO CART
</a></div>
<script language="javascript">
function updatelink (link)
{
    var a = document.getElementById("cartbutton");
    a.href = link;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response - but it still goes to the link thats in the button. I have a link in the button like the options thats a query string to add to cart. Its really just the first options link (green) which is empty. So right now when I try it your way, it keeps adding GREEN. Any ideas?

Comment: I didnt put this in a form, do I need to <form></form>

Comment: please check now, there were error in updatelink function calling on selection change, also you will need to set value of option green.

Comment: no need to have form on the page, but jquery is required, if you are not using jquery let me know, i will update with plain javascript.

Comment: keeps adding green. Should I remove the button link? I beleive jquery is being called on the page but plain js may help. THanks again Vaibhav

Comment: if you want to keep green as empty do it like <option value="">Green</option>, but you will need to set its value.

Comment: you are welcome david, i have update code to use plain js instead of jquery, also full refresh the page to load the changes. please try and let me know.

Comment: It still didnt do exactly what I wanted. It still only ever adds the green option. The add to cart shouldnt be a link I dont think. I should remove that href because it was only there as the default option (green) hence green not having a link. So how can I change that add to cart link so it goes to the link from only the option selected. So if they click purple, it goes to 
/checkout/cart/add?product=131&options[912]=4990